# onClientClick with JavaScript function and eval

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a button within a repeater that needs to call a function. When `someVariable` is an `int`, runs just fine. However, when `someVariable` is a string, the call breaks. In the page source, I can see that the string is evaluated without single quotes in the `someMethod` call, so I tried added the escape `\'` to insert single quotes. No go. I've tried String.Format() as well, to no avail. What am I missing?

```
OnClientClick= '<%# "return someMethod(" + Eval("someVariable") + ");" %>'
```

*breaks when someVariable is a string

Comment: Please be more clear and give detailed code.

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ The example that does not call String.Format() in the possible duplicate is identical to mine. I'll try the String.Format() examples now, however.

Comment: Also, the "possible duplicated" results in a Parser Error regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onClientClick= '<%# String.Format("return someMethod(&#39;{0}&#39;);", Eval("someVariable")) %>'
```

where `someVariable` is a string;

The 'duplicate answer' that is linked to at the top works fine when `someVariable` is numeric. When it's a string, `\'` does not work to escape the single quotation mark, but ' will work in this case.